# Bounding the size of the dual solution

Tags: integer-programming

Given an primal optimization with bounded feasible set: $\max \{cx: Ax \leq b\}$.

The feasible region of the dual is $D = \{y:y^\top A = c^\top, y \geq 0\}$.

If the primal feasbile region is a polytope, then the dual might still by an polyhedron (not bounded in all directions).

Each polyhedron can be written as a convex part plus a cone ($V$-representation of polytopes).

How can I get an upper bound $u$ on the values of $y$ in the convex part?
(the bound should say that all verticies of $D$ have entries smaller than $u$?)

The bound obviously needs to depend on $c$ and $A$.

Comment: You could use Cramer's rule on all possible basic solutions of the dual to obtain some bound. Still, I think this is of no practical use.

Comment: Is a non-convex formulation acceptable?

Comment: i was looking for something simple and easy to solve.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no easy general upper bound available. This is a central problem in MILP-representations in bilevel programming, and as discussed here http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2019/04/7172.pdf it is hard